# Cannot get WebClient.DownloadString to download inside a Task on mono

Tags: mono, webclient

This test code works in Windows as expected:

```
        var urls5 = urls.Take(100);
        var elapsed5 = Test<WebClient>(urls5);
        Console.WriteLine("Webclient:" + elapsed5);
```

using the method (excuse the Console.WriteLines):

```
    static TimeSpan Test<T>(IEnumerable<string> urls) where T : WebClient, new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("2");
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var u in urls)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("3");
                using (var wc = new T())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("4");
                    var str = wc.DownloadString(u);
                    Console.WriteLine("5");
                    var hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    hap.LoadHtml(str);

                    var asdf = hap.DocumentNode.InnerText + " ";

                    Console.Write(".");
                }
            }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed;
    }
```

However in mono (windows and linux), judging from the writelines, each task only gets up to "4" and not beyond, throwing timeout exceptions. Without tasks, the test code works on mono as expected. Am I doing something wrong, or have I inadvertently stumbled upon a bug?

Interestingly, if I run the code in XamarinStudio's debug mode, it receives the downloaded content.

Comment: please report mono bugs in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: That's why I asked if I had done anything wrong! I did report it, but 2 days without any activity.

Comment: if you reported it, then link to the url of it here please